# Query where substr Codeigniter

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter, where-clause

I have to check two characters of a string in the database.
here is my code but it does not work.

```
    function getby_substr() {
    $query =  $this->db
                   ->where('substr(ipv6, 4,2 )', 'c1')
                   ->get('computer_information');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    return array();
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Try where condition with normal query like this: 
$this->db->where("SUBSTR(ipv6,4,2) = 'c1'");

Comment: more details for column and value match against

Comment: Thank you  Pragya!

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this helps you :**

With `where` clause

```
      /*replace column_name with your table field name*/
      $query =  $this->db
               ->where('column_name', SUBSTRING(ipv6, 2, 5))
               ->get('computer_information');
```

With `like` clause

```
     $query =  $this->db
               ->like('column_name', SUBSTRING(ipv6, 2, 5))
               ->get('computer_information');
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data